# PyQGIS 3 vector layer labeling settings dialog

Tags: labeling, pyqgis-3

I am working on a PyQGIS standalone application with the latest QGIS 3 libraries and in Python 3.7. I would like to allow users to modify any vector layer's labeling style, I know in QGIS program, one can just right click on a layer and go to its properties, I would like to open up that labeling dialog directly, but I couldn't find the right dialog to call.

Anyone know what `QgsXXXDialog` that I can call for label setting configuration? (I know I can build one myself, but really want to use one from QGIS python API)

Comment: look at this https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/305551/49538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trials, `QgsTextFormatDialog` is the control for getting user-specified font formatting, then one takes that formatting and applies to the labeling of a vector layer