# Which PyQGIS class is the layer properties menu?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt5

I have a plugin which I want to add options to either the context menu when right clicking a layer at the `Layers` panel or the properties menu for that layer.

How can I call them from PyQGIS?
Can I add the options every time the plugin loads?
It feels like the properties menu should be [qgis.gui.QgsLayerPropertiesWidget](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsLayerPropertiesWidget.html) but it seems to be mapped by symbol layers and not map layers.
I can't find any class that seems to fit the right click context menu in the layer panel.

How can I do this?

## EDIT 1

Luis Perez's answer was what i wanted.
I meanwhile found the way to add actions to the right click context menu, so posting this here for anyone else looking

```
def printSomething():
    print('Yay a new action!')
    
customAction = QAction('Print Something Nice')
customAction.triggered.connect(printSomething)
iface.addCustomActionForLayerType(customAction,'',qgis.core.QgsMapLayerType(0),True)
```

This will add the action `Print Something Nice` to all the Vector layers in your project.

[image]

This can be further customized by connecting the action to other signals instead of `triggered`, like `hovered` for instance.

Comment: You cannot add a new option to the context menu, because it is created simultaneously when right clicking any layer.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz Apparently you can, stumbled upon it not long ago. check out the edit just made.

Comment: I missed that. I couldn't add it before. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was answered here [Getting Layer Properties of QGIS on standalone application using PyQGIS API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305551/getting-layer-properties-of-qgis-on-standalone-application-using-pyqgis-api)

It seems that the layer properties dialog is not accessible via PyQGIS but its individual parts are.

For example, try this on a vector layer, especially as you point out the symbol

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
d = QgsLayerPropertiesWidget(QgsSimpleLineSymbolLayer(), QgsLineSymbol(), layer)
d.showPanel()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome, at your service. By the way, brilliant code that you shared on the menu when you right clicked on the layer

Comment: Came by it by accident while trying to solve this on my own. It would have been better to be able to add a QPushButton or just a widget but using the QAction is fine too.